# React - Wrong component rendering after calling history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a pretty basic app with just a few pages: home, login and dashboard. The goal is for a user to successfully login and be navigated to the dashboard. Currently after I click the login form the `url/path` update in the browser to `/dashboard`, but I still see the `auth` component. I can only see the dashboard component if I do a refresh in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-scqvhp

```
"react": "^16.11.0",
"react-dom": "^16.11.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "3.2.0"
```

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/auth">
              <Auth />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/dashboard">
              <Dashboard />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Auth.js

```
export default function Auth() {
  let match = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div className="d-flex align-items-center bg-auth border-top border-top-2 border-primary vh-100">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          <div className="col-12 col-md-5 col-xl-4 my-5">
            <p>Auth</p>
            <Router>
              <Route path={`${match.path}/login`}><Login /></Route>
            </Router>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Login.js

```
export default function Login() {
  let history = useHistory();

  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    history.push('/dashboard');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submit}  data-op-form-id="0">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Email Address</label>
          <input type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="name@address.com" />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
              <label>Password</label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-auto">
              <a href="#" className="form-text small text-muted">
                Forgot password?
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="input-group input-group-merge">
            <input type="password" className="form-control form-control-appended" placeholder="Enter your password" />
            <div className="input-group-append">
                  <span className="input-group-text">
                    <Eye/>
                  </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary mb-3">Sign in</button>
        <div className="text-center">
          <small className="text-muted text-center">Don't have an account yet? <a href="#">Sign up</a>.</small>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Dashboard.js

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar/>
      <p>Dashboard</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your routes weren't correctly set. Here's a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hyabkk)

```
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/auth">
            <Auth />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/auth/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/dashboard">
            <Dashboard />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</Router>
```

Also **remove** the router from `auth.js`

```
<Router>
   <Route path={`${match.path}/login`}><Login /></Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: It's great that you fixed the issue, but it would be even better if you altered your answer to explain *what* you changed and *why* it fixes the issue

Comment: Like I said the routes weren't set properly The OP only needed to add the proper routes in this case /auth/login and about the nested router it's not needed

Answer (score 1):

Remove the nested `Router` in `Auth`, it will be conflicting with the URL routing i.e. there is no `/dashboard` route declared for nested router therefore it renders the `Auth` view with no child view

```
export default function Auth() {
  let match = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div className="d-flex align-items-center bg-auth border-top border-top-2 border-primary vh-100">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          <div className="col-12 col-md-5 col-xl-4 my-5">
            <p>Auth</p>
            <Route path={`${match.path}/login`}><Login /></Route>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

You should only need one instance of `Router` per app, see the [docs on nesting](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting)